Does this board already have pull up resistors for I2C?
I want to use this type of Nucleo board to communicate with a device which requires both SPI and I2C protocols.
I know that SPI is directly connected but I2C requires pullup resistors.
Does it mean either the device or the MCU has to provide pullup resistors? And in the document I linked at the end there's schematic. I couldn't be sure if such resistors already installed in the board or not(?)

Which pins do you intend to use for SCL/SDA? Generally, these boards are very basic (for flexibility), so it's unlikely the pull-ups are provided (I certainly can't see any in the schematic)... Internal pull-ups are likely too weak for you to achieve a decent bus speed, so you'll need to provide them externally or on the peripheral board.

Check the eval board schematic

It is unlikely that an MCU board would have fixed I2C pullup resistors because (a) it makes the pins more difficult to use for other purposes, (b) because I2C would probably anway attempt to use internal pin pullups (but these are normally quite weak) (c) the pins from the I2C peripheral may be mapped selectively to many different GPIO pins and (d) most modules have them anyway. There the big problem is to ensure that there are not too many I2C pullups on the bus. There should be a maximum pullup load (say 4.7k) on the bus as general starting point.
The Nucleo board schematic does not appear to show dedicated I2C pullup resistors (at a quick glance)
